# In TYPO3 6.1 fluid, how to correctly write conditions in a Partial?

Tags: typo3, fluid, extbase

In my extbase/fluid extension, I can get "if" conditions to work in a List template, but not in a Partial.

```
<f:if condition="item.label == 0">xxx</f:if>
```

returns true and writes out "xxx" no matter what item.typ's value is.

Is that the right syntax for a condition in a partial?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it. The field name needs to be in curly brackets:

```
  <f:if condition="{item.label} == 0">xxx</f:if>
```